# Why is the theoretically faster method of providing an initial subset of data not?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have some pages that display LOTS of images (small, but still lots of them).

I've got two ways of showing a subset of the page first, so the user doesn't have to wait for the whole shebang to download before seeing anything on the page, and then replacing that with everything, which is in a .json file that is parsed via jQuery.

At first, I did it this way:

```
var placeholderForOscars = "<div class=\"yearBanner\">2012</div><section class=\"wrapper\" ><a id=\"mainImage\" class=\"floatLeft\" href=\" . . . (etc) </section>";
$('#MoviesContent').html(placeholderForOscars);
getMovies('Content/oscars.json');
```

...but then I thought it would be faster/more elegant to put the data in the "placeholder" var in a file and do it this way:

```
$('#MusicContent').load('Content/grammies.html');
getMusic('Content/grammies.json');
```

IOW, in both cases I put the first page or so worth of html on the page, and subsequently replace that with all of the data (after it has been spun through/parsed, and turned into html).

I expected the second way to be faster, but there is a delay before the page loads, just as if I weren't calling load() at all. Am I doing it wrong, or is load slower than my original method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` is asynchronous, it has to make a whole new request to the server to get the data. Since it's not that much data, it's far more efficient to just inline it like in your first code block.